# Wait until child Thread Finishe, But Do Not Block Main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, executorservice

I have been working on a java GUI application that on a particular action do some task. I have been doing this task using ExecutorService. Now the working with multiple threads works fine but the problem is that I do not want to block my GUI. User may want to cancel the current operation and may request for another one. But while using the ExecutorService, my main Thread gets blocked. I want to wait for my child threads to finish, invoked using ExecutorService, while still being able to work on GUI.

The updated code is:

```
    ExecutorService child = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@Action
public void doAction() {
    /** Some Code goes here */
    if(Condition){
        if(!(es.isTerminated()||es.isShutdown())){
            es.shutdownNow();
            es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        }
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(!(child.isTerminated()||child.isShutdown())){
                    child.shutdownNow();
                    child = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                }
                for(loopConditions){
                    child.execute(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //Perform Some Task Here
                        }
                    });
                }
                child.shutdown();
                try {
                    boolean finshed = child.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    child.shutdownNow();
                    Logger.getLogger(MySearchView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("All Child Threads finished Execution");
            }
        });
        es.shutdown();
        try {
            boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            es.shutdownNow();
            Logger.getLogger(MySearchView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("All Threads finished Execution");
        /**
        * Code that should run after all Threads finishes their Execution
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: whats reason for using ExecutorService (sure nothing wrong), maybe there are another way, maybe ExecutorService is proper of ways

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `Executor`s in the way they're intended. They are meant to be long-lived, created on application startup and torn down at the end. Don't use `shutdownNow` and `awaitTermination` during normal processing.

If you want to await the result of a task, call `get()` on the `Future` that was returned when you submitted it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ScheduledExecutorService to shut itself down after 5 seconds.

Comment: But I can't shut it down so early. The action may take a few sec to a few minutes to complete and if user don't want to initiate a new action it should continue.

Comment: In that case I would save the future and cancel it when you have a new action. `if(future != null) future.cancel(true); future = es.submit(new MyNewTask());`